# jackson serializer: get serialized object

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonserializer

I have a problem with Serializer, here is my problem :

I have a bean class like that :

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyObjectSerializer.class)
public class MyObject {
    public int a;
    public boolean b;
}
```

When Serializing through Jackson, without the @ JsonSerialize annotation, I obviously get :

```
{ "a": 42, "b": true}
```

But I need to add a property so it gives :

```
{ "a": 42, "b": true, "version": "0.1-beta" }
```

*(This is an example, in the real world, the property I add depends on several properties of the object)*

So I need to write a custom serializer.
However, in my real code, the class contains much more properties than just 2. So I don't want to manually create those properties to the json object...

If I use this :

```
public static class MyObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<MyObject> {
    @Override public void serialize(MyObject obj, JsonGenerator json, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        json.writeObject(obj);
    }
}
```

I obviously get a StackOverflowError.

So the question can be :

- **How, from inside a JsonSerializer can I serialize the object without re-calling the serializer itself ?**

or

- **How can I dynamically add properties to an object beeing serialized.**

I used to do that all the time with GSon but Jackson provides loads of feature that I would love to use ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure a getter, in your example `getVersion()`, without a backing property would suffice, in which you'd generate `0.1-beta`. (or generate the value based on the values of a couple of properties as you describe).

So no need for a custom serializer just for this purpose